# How do you change the windows console icon in python code?

Tags: python, windows, configuration, console

I can add this code to my python script to configure the windows console.
How do you change the default windows console icon?

os.system('mode con: cols=90 lines=28')

Comment: Welcome to SO! That code calls out to the Windows console `mode` command. There is no console command to do what you want. The icon comes from a resource within the executable.  I think the only way to do what you want would be to make your own variant of `cmd.exe` with a different embedded icon. That would be a quite ambitious project.

Comment: Awesome! I figured as much. It's good to see some one with Python skills appreciate the question and reach out so quickly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @BoarGules could you please convert the comment to an answer? :]

Also, if it helps, there is a `title` command that could at least change the window title, if not the icon.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the icon of the window, but you need to know the window's title. Here's some code that will set the title, wait for it to apply, then update the icon.

```
import win32gui
import os
import time

def set_window_title(window_title_string, wait_for_change=False):
    os.system("title " + window_title_string)
    if (wait_for_change):
        matched_window = 0
        while (matched_window == 0):
            matched_window = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_title_string)
            time.sleep(0.025) # To not flood it too much...
    
    return window_title_string

def set_window_icon(window_title, image_path):
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_title)
    icon_flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
    hicon = win32gui.LoadImage(None, image_path, win32con.IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, icon_flags)
    
    win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_SETICON, win32con.ICON_SMALL, hicon)
    win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_SETICON, win32con.ICON_BIG, hicon)

def set_title_and_icon(window_title, icon_path):
    """Set the window title, wait for it to apply, then adjust the icon."""
    window_title = set_window_title(window_title, wait_for_change=True)
    set_window_icon(window_title, image_path)
    return window_title

set_title_and_icon("Cool Title Name", "C:\Users\youruser\an_icon.ico")
```

The `window_title` variable is passed back in case you wanted to add a unique ID or something similar when the title is set in `set_window_title`.